# NodeJs. Problem with module.export; it is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have written this piece of code:

```
function newExercise(data){
    pool.query('INSERT INTO Exercises VALUES(?, ?)', [data, data], function(error, results, field){
        if(error) console.log(error);
    })
}

module.exports = {
    newExercise: newExercise,
}
```

But when I call the function from here:

```
Promise.all([exname, exdesc])
    .then( values => {
        router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
            var socket = req.app.get('socket');
            io = req.app.get('socketio');
            io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
                socket.on('message', function(message){
                    console.log("Ricevuto");
                    database.newExcercise(message);
                })
            })
            res.render('exercises', {title: 'Exercises', ex: values[0]});
        })
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

I get "TypeError: database.newExcercise is not a function", but I don't understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above code snippet, you defined the function as:
`newExercise`, and in the second snippet, you're calling it as `newExcercise`.

It's a simple typo.

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was removing a circular reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: `module.exports.newExercise = newExercise;`

Answer (score 0):

file name NewExercise.js

```
module.exports = function newExercise(data){
   pool.query('INSERT INTO Exercises VALUES(?, ?)', [data, data], function(error, results, field){
      if(error) console.log(error);
   })
}
```

in another file where you are calling this function you just
`var newExercise= require('./NewExercise.js');`
and you just call it
`newExercise(message)`